# Are any anti-theft GPS trackers dynamo powered?

Tags: gps, theft, dynamo

I am considering an anti-theft GPS tracker for my bicycle, but I am worried about battery life.

Are there any that recharge from a hub dynamo?

Answer (score 4):

I use this product:

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Spybike-Bike-GPS-Tracker-to-spy-and-pretect-your-bike-with-ease-New-bike-tail-light/32251529357.html

Since this is a tail light, it is less suspicious as a GPS tracker. You can simply charge and remove the USB cable as well.

(One thing to notice since this product is not inexpensive, I epoxied the screw just to be on the safe side :D )

---

For anyone without a USB 5V DC port from your dynamo hub:

1. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/BICYCLE-DYNAMO-USB-REGULATOR-PDA-PHONE-USB-CHARGER-M172-/370935357198?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item565d785f0e
2. [Tigra Sport Bike Charge Power Conterter](http://www.halfords.com/cycling/cycling-technology/cycle-computers-gps/tigra-sport-bike-charge-power-conterter?cm_mmc=Google%20PLA-_-Cycling%20Technology-_-Cycle%20Computers%20and%20GPS-_-698674&_$ja=tsid:60494%7Ccgn:GoogleShopping%7Ckw:698674&istCompanyId=b8708c57-7a02-4cf6-b2c0-dc36b54a327e&istItemId=xmqpapiir&istBid=tzxm&_$$ja=cgid:16790764204%7Ctsid:35522%7Ccid:214996084%7Clid:50613723535%7Cnw:g%7Ccrid:73916133724%7Crnd:865581983920909088%7Cdvc:c%7Cadp:1o1%7Cbku:1&__ja=cgid:16790764204%7Ctsid:35522%7Ccid:214996084%7Clid:50613723535%7Cnw:g%7Ccrid:73916133724%7Crnd:865581983920909088%7Cdvc:c%7Cadp:1o1%7Ckw:&gclid=Cj0KEQjw_rytBRDVhZeQrbzn_q0BEiQAjnbSHJ_8rFMnaVxoJUac4SPJAWcO-_7lDug16mJxanbuXQAaApP-8P8HAQ)

or.. just search google for "Hub dynamo USB" if you are not from the UK :D

3. and for anyone who loves DIY to make your own AC-DC regulator:
   https://parttimetinkerer.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/charging-usb-devices-from-a-hub-dynamo/

Comment: That's cool! Seems like that would work with any tracker that can recharge with a USB connection.

Comment: yeah, it's pretty convenient. I occasionally plug it onto my phone battery extension for my half hour ride and it works for a week.

Comment: Does your hub put out DC? Did you include a rectifier in the wiring? Or, does the light/tracker tolerate AC?

Comment: thanks, I completely forgot about that important step!! Update now :D

Answer (score 1):

Most of the ones that I've seen are all battery powered – there is one, [Shy Spy](http://interestingengineering.com/shyspy-tracking-device/), that appears to have an inductive charger. The problem that I imagine with a dynamo powered tracker is that the power cable could lead the thief to the location of the tracker on your bike.

Another option would be to have the tracker generate its own power. The [Connected Cycle Pedals](http://connectedcycle.com) do that.